# Obtener el tamaño en mb o kb de una imagen partir de un arreglo en Visual Basic

Tags: vb

Digamos que tengo una imagen de unos 5mb, despues transformo esa imagen en bytes con la siguiente funcion:

```
Public Function ImagenToByte(ByVal img As Image) As Byte()
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
        img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat)
        ImagenToByte = ms.GetBuffer
    End Function
```

Luego usando esta variable almaceno alli la imagen en bytes:

```
Dim imagenenbytes As Byte() = ImagenToByte(imgFoto.Image)
```

Mi duda es como puedo obtener el valor del tamaño de la imagen en bytes? es decir apartir de la varible que en este caso se llama imagenenbytes, me tendria que decir que el tamaño es de 5mb o 5.120 kb

Comment: Si tienes los bytes de la imagen en un arreglo debería ser tan simple como obtener el tamaño del arreglo. Otra opción es multiplicar ancho por alto por en número de bytes que ocupa cada pixel. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: te explico: use una imagen de 4.788kb y con la funcion: "imagenenbytes.Length" y me da como resultado "5169664", tambien use la funcion "My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(dlg.FileName).Length" y me da como resultado "4902617". la segunda funcion me devuelve el valor correcto sin embargo esta obtiene la imagen desde una direccion y yo necesito que obtener el valor a partir del arreglo de bytes, como seria la segunda opcion que me planteas, si puedes por favor pasame codigo

Comment: No acabo de entender a qué se debe la diferencia entre ambos. Otra opción es calcular el tamaño mediante el ancho por alto por el número de bytes que ocupa en memoria cada pixel: `tamaño = alto * ancho * bytesPorPixel`. Los bytes por pixel los puedes sacar de la propiedad `PixelFormat` de la imagen.

Comment: mira lo hice asi:

Dim pixeles As Integer = imgFoto.Image.PixelFormat
Dim ancho As Integer = imgFoto.Image.Width
Dim alto As Long = imgFoto.Image.Height

Dim tamañoreal As String = ancho * alto * pixeles

y el resultado que me da tamañoreal es de 1367848832000, que tengo que hacer ahora, lo divido o resto? y en que unidades?

Comment: Pero lee un momento la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) lo más probable es que el formato sea Format32bppArgb en cuyo caso son 4 bytes por píxel.